# ABP.IO CLI: Trying to use create an application from a custom template using templates\app folder from the repo

Tags: abp

I cloned https://github.com/abpframework/abp to D:\abp
I am following documentation: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/CLI-New-Command-Samples

I want to create MVC UI, Entity Framework Core, no mobile app, using the template in D:\abp\templates\app directory.
So I want to use:
-custom template
-local ABP framework references

I wanted to make a simple change inside this page:
D:\abp\templates\app\aspnet-core\src\MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Web\Pages\Index.cshtml

from:
<h1>Welcome to the Application</h1> to
<h1>Welcome to the MY NEW APPLICATION</h1>

I issued this command:

**D:\TestApps>abp new Acme.BookStore -t app -csf true -u mvc -d ef --tiered -separate-identity-server --no-random-port --connection-string "Server=localhost;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True" --template-source
D:\abp\templates\app --local-framework-ref --abp-path D:\abp**

It seems that abp.io cli requires a .specific version of .zip file to be here: D:\abp\templates\app\ and theres folder needs to be zipped in app-4.4.3.zip:
-angular
-aspnet-core
-react-native

Is this intentional? Should the documentation mentioned that we need to zip folder for a particular type of starter template?

Here is the error:

```
[05:56:38 INF] ABP CLI (https://abp.io)
[05:56:39 INF] Version 4.4.3 (Stable)
[05:56:40 INF] Creating your project...
[05:56:40 INF] Project name: Acme.BookStore
[05:56:40 INF] Template: app
[05:56:40 INF] Tiered: yes
[05:56:40 INF] Database provider: EntityFrameworkCore
[05:56:40 INF] Connection string: Server=localhost;Database=TestRenaming;Trusted_Connection=True
[05:56:40 INF] UI Framework: Mvc
[05:56:40 INF] GitHub Abp Local Repository Path: D:\abp
[05:56:40 INF] Template Source: D:\abp\templates\app
[05:56:40 INF] Output folder: D:\TestApps\Acme.BookStore
[05:56:41 INF] Using local template: app, version: 4.4.3
[05:56:41 ERR] Could not find file 'D:\abp\templates\app\app-4.4.3.zip'.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\abp\templates\app\app-4.4.3.zip'.
```

Comment: looks like they forgot to update the templates

Answer (score 0):

[It seems it is by design that abp cli expects a zipped themplates with versioning. They should mentioned that in the documentation](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/10486)